# How to make text within nodes findable in cytoscape.js, dagre-layout

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have been trying to use the dagre-layout in cytoscape.js to create a graph, however I seem unable to find the text within nodes, which I am able to do in dagre-d3, (EDIT: Find as in CTRL + F).

It seems like even in demos such as: http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/labels/ this is not available.

Any ideas on how to make it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to search based on label content or are you asking about a way to display a label (in which case, add some visualisation of what you're trying to achieve)?

Comment: I'm just trying to do CTRL + F to find a label.

Comment: cytoscape exists in a canvas, so I don't think it should ever be possible to achieve ctrl+f search (which, as far as i know, only searches in text-based content).
You could easily implement a separate search bar to achieve similar functionality within your cytoscape instance(s), though

Answer (score 3):

When working with Cytoscape, you're not working with traditional DOM elements for the nodes and edges. Rather it draws on a canvas. So are you screwed?

Nope. You just need to program a bit. Add a text box to your page. Add an on change listener to it (or add a button to search only when the user clicks it). When the user types, you can run a search that reads through all of the nodes in the graph. For speed you might want to implement a [binary search](https://codeburst.io/binary-search-in-javascript-a-practical-example-7fda60ce59a1) based on the node's text.

When you find text that matches (exact or partial), you can add a class to change the visual appearance using Cytoscape.js' [addClass](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.addClass) method. You decision of how to show the data is up to you.